# How to create a basic page

Tags: 7

This is a really dumb question, but I simply want to create a basic page with it's own path, (i.e. mysite.com/contact) so far I've only had to use Views to display node data. Views have the option of specifying a path, but I'm assuming I don't have to create a view to display a regular page?

The Drupal docs say the default installation comes with the "Basic page" content type, so I tried creating that content type, but I can't see an option to specify a path...

I feel very silly >.<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't set the path when creating a content type. Once you create a "basic page" content type (or use the one that comes with the "standard Install" of Drupal core), you can then create a basic page by going to node/add. Then in the vertical tabs at the bottom of the node creation page, you will find a tab called, "URL path settings". In there you can manually specify a path. If you wish to avoid having to manually adding a path for every node, use the [Pathauto](http://www.drupal.org/pathauto) module.